# another TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

So, i found this piece of magic some time ago and it worked perfectly

```
import os
import sys
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib
import urllib2
import json as simplejson

searchTerm = "somethingsomething"

searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(' ','%20')


class MyOpener(FancyURLopener): 
   version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'

myopener = MyOpener()

count= 0

for i in range(0,10):
   url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?' + 'v=1.0&q='+searchTerm+'&start='+str(i*4)+'&userip=MyIP')
print("url")
   request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
   response = urllib2.urlopen(request)


   results = simplejson.load(response)
   data = results['responseData']
   dataInfo = data['results']


for myUrl in dataInfo:
    count = count + 1
    print("myUrl['unescapedUrl']")

    myopener.retrieve(myUrl['unescapedUrl'],str(count)+'.jpg')

time.sleep(1)
```

few days ago i wanted to use it again and got this error:

> dataInfo = data['results']
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

I am using the same version of python as before (2.6)
I don't know how to fix this, is it api or what, anyone?

(To clarify: I am using this to my artistic project, I don't know how to "really" code, so please guys, be gentle with me ;) I know that there is similar question to mine, but I don't know how to apply answer to my problem...)

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but Python 2.6? Why? Also, indentation is important in python. It would appear most the code under `for i in range(0,10):` needs indented.

Comment: oh, yeah, I just screwed indentation while copying here ;)

Comment: Regarding your comment below. Read the message at the top of this page.  https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not correctly indented. Also, `results['responseData']` is `None` with a `responseDetails` that says `This API is no longer available.` So, you do not have `results['responseData']['results']` at all.

```
>>> url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=somethingsomething&start=36&userip=MyIP'
>>>
>>> request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>> results = simplejson.load(response)
>>> print(results)
{u'responseData': None, u'responseDetails': u'This API is no longer available.', u'responseStatus': 403}
>>>
>>>
>>> data = results['responseData']
>>> dataInfo = data['results']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Comment: do you have any idea what api should I use instead?

Comment: No, you need to look at their documentation to see what is the alternative now.